# Possible to use angular-datatables with serverside array sourced data instead of object sourced data

Tags: datatables, angular-datatables

I'm trying to use angular-datatables with serverside processing.  However, it seems that angular-datatables expects that the data from the server is in object format ([object vs array data described](https://datatables.net/manual/data/)) with column names preceding each table datapoint.  I'd like to configure angular-datatables to accept array based data since I can't modify my server side output which only outputs data in array format.

I'm configuring Datatables in my javascript like so:

```js
var vm = this;
vm.dtOptions = DTOptionsBuilder.newOptions()
    .withOption('ajax', {
     url: 'output/ss_results/' + $routeParams.uuid,
     type: 'GET'
 })
 .withDataProp('data')
 .withOption('processing', true)
 .withOption('serverSide', true);
```

My data from the server looks like this in array format:

```js
var data = [
    [
        "Tiger Nixon",
        "System Architect",
        "$3,120"
    ],
    [
        "Garrett Winters",
        "Director",
        "$5,300"
    ]
]
```

But as far as I can tell, angular-datatables is expecting the data in object format like so:

```js
[
    {
        "name":       "Tiger Nixon",
        "position":   "System Architect",
        "extn":       "5421"
    },
    {
        "name":       "Garrett Winters",
        "position":   "Director",
        "extn":       "8422"
    }
]
```

I tried not defining dtColumns or setting it to an empty array like `vm.dtColumns = [];` but I get an error message when I do that.  When I configure dtColumns with a promise to load the column data via ajax I get datatables error #4 because it can't find the column name preceding my table datapoints in the data retrieved from the server.

**Is it possible to configure angular-datatables to accept array based data?**  I can't find anything on the [angular-datatables website](http://l-lin.github.io/angular-datatables/#/serverSideProcessing) that indicates it can be configured this way.

**Edit**: So I removed the `.withDataProp('data')` which I think was causing the problem.  The table works a little better now but it's still broken.  After it loads, I get the message `No matching records found`.  Even though right below it it says `Showing 1 to 10 of 60,349 entries
Previous1…456…6035Next`  Does anyone know why this might be?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to use an array of arrays instead of an array of objects, simply refer to the array *indexes* instead of the object names :

```js
$scope.dtColumns = [
   DTColumnBuilder.newColumn(0).withTitle('Name'),
   DTColumnBuilder.newColumn(1).withTitle('Position'),
   DTColumnBuilder.newColumn(2).withTitle('Office'),
   DTColumnBuilder.newColumn(3).withTitle('Start date'),
   DTColumnBuilder.newColumn(4).withTitle('Salary')
]
```

demo using the famous "Tiger Nixon" array loaded via AJAX -> **http://plnkr.co/edit/16UoRqF5hvg2YpvAP8J3?p=preview**